# Ajax Load - Form Submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a website I'm building and it is set up so that when a link is pressed on the left, the page content is loaded in a div on the right.

```
<div id="right-column">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dataReturn='';

    function makeRequest(url){
        $('#preloader').show();
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#resultDiv').html(data);
            $('#preloader').hide();
        });
    }

    function makePostRequest(url, params){
        $('#preloader').show();
        $.post(url,params, function(data){
            $('#resultDiv').html(data);
            $('#preloader').hide();
        });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="preloader"></div>
<div id="resultDiv">    
<h3>Welcome <?php echo $user_identity;?></h3>
<h5>Message: <?php echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT message FROM staff_misc");?></h5>    
</div>

</div>
```

Now this works fine for the links loading the content they're supposed to... now my question is. One of the pages has a form with the following code:

```
<h3>Admin Message</h3>

<form id="message" method="post" action="Admin/message.php">
<input type="text" style="width:700px;" value="Set A New Message" name="admin-message"/>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) ) //If submit is hit
{

$message = $_POST["admin-message"];
$wpdb->query("UPDATE staff_misc set Message = '$message' where id = '1'");

?><b>New Message Set:</b> <?php echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT message FROM staff_misc");?><?php

}
```

If that form is submitted, it refreshes the whole page rather than reloading the content back in to the AJAX div. How do I go about making it so that page loads back in to the AJAX div rather than refreshing the entire page and losing the left column with the links.

Answer (score 1):

You can either capture the submit event on the form, cancel the default action, and redirect it to your own form handler, then submit via AJAX.....or you can change the submit button to a regular button that calls your form handler, then submit via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a submit handler for that form, and make sure to return false at the end of your function, to stop the default action for the form.

```
$('#message').on('submit', function() {
    $.post('Admin/message.php', $('#message').serialize(), function( html ){
       // do something with return message
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be something like this:

```
<script>
  $("#message").submit(function() {
    // do something...

    // this will prevent the event from bubbling and keep the page from refreshing
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How do I include: $message = $_POST["admin-message"];
$wpdb->query("UPDATE staff_misc set Message = '$message' where id = '1'");

?><b>New Message Set:</b> <?php echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT message FROM staff_misc");?> in the do something part though?

Comment: Normally, a form will make a new request to the server and the response will be loaded by the browser, losing any changes in the page which have happened via ajax.

If you want to keep track of the page's state, you'll have to track that in some way through get variables (like with searching and sorting) or by storing information in the session somehow.

Or, you can activate the above php code you mentioned by putting it in its own file and making an ajax request to it.

You have to maintain the page state somehow if you aren't going to use ajax so it can be rebuilt by the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

First Page:

```
    <h3>Admin Message</h3>

    <form id="message" method="post" action="Admin/message.php">
    <input type="text" style="width:700px;" value="Set A New Message" name="admin-message" id="admin-message" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".submit").click(function(e){

     //Prevent the entire page from refreshig
     e.preventDefault();

     $.get("ajax.php?admin-message=" + $("#admin-message").val(), function(result){

          $("#result").html(result);

     });     

    });

    </script>
```

ajax.php

```
    <?php

if ( isset ( $_POST['submit'] ) ) //If submit is hit
{

$message = $_POST["admin-message"];
$wpdb->query("UPDATE staff_misc set Message = '$message' where id = '1'");

?><b>New Message Set:</b> <?php echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT message FROM staff_misc");?><?php

}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: sorry, i was away? have u fixed it?